# Facebook like buttons were disappeared after doing "like"

Tags: javascript, facebook

There is no way that I figure out what happens on my website...

sharing debugger tells me Okay.
Open Graph debugger tells me Okay, also.

the like button would be shown before doing like...

but, after doing like, it's just disappeared from every users... (even unsigned)

settings are fine. it means "there is no country lock, 14+ years old.".

...

chrome, firefox, opera, IE... the problem is same on all browsers.
even in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button, the button will not be appeared.

here's my code.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : '***********************',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like"
     data-href="{{ $URL }}"
     data-layout="button_count"
     data-action="like"
     data-size="small"
     data-show-faces="true"
     data-share="false"></div>
```

have any idea?

Comment: The idea would be to check the Facebook bug tracker before panicking ... this is a current bug, has already been reported, and they are working on it.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. you've given me hope.